# What to do when a question justifies an extended response?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure what to do.

I answered a question about Use Case relationships by linking to a resource that

1. Is one of the most popular explanations of the subject on the web
2. Saves me from duplicating an already well thought out and well structured explanation
3. Does not 'self-promote' or attempt to sell other unrelated services
4. Was written by me as a carefully crafted response to the actual question and is not just a generic paper.

...and yet my post was deleted - Why?

Of course I could have cut'n'pasted the explanation rather than linking to it, but that just seems dumb - the question deserves a proper response that needs multiple diagrams with assocated explanations. To answer the question properly, with a carefully reasoned response so that we minimise the prospect of further mis-undertandings took 8 or 9 pages. Too long to post on the board itself.

Question is here

[What's is the difference between include and extend in use case diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696927/whats-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-use-case-diagram)

answer is here

http://www.karonaconsulting.com/downloads/UseCases_IncludesAndExtends.pdf

Comment: If you had posted only a link to it, it would have been deleted as it is "policy" to remove posts which do not provide an answer without the links in the post.

Comment: Ok I get that. But how much of the answer do I need to provide 'in post' to meet the requirements? Why encourage me to cut'n'paste?

Comment: Rule of thumb: if a 9-page PDF file is required to answer a question, the question is too broad. *(By the way, that question was posted back in 2009. Try posting it now and see what happens.)*

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - in this case it is not the breadth of the question, it is the requirements for the depth of the answer. It would be easy to provide a short response, but to do so simply breeds further questions.

Comment: *It would be easy to provide a short response, but to do so simply breeds further questions.* And that's why the question is too broad (even though it is quite short in length).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - I don't understand the reference to the date of the question? Why are only 'new' questions worth a proper answer?

Comment: It's a little complicated. The rules have changed since 2009, and questions like this would be closed now. That means the community does not want these questions to be answered now. Some of us extend the consensus to older questions: if you don't want *new* questions like this to be answered *now*, why would you want *older* questions like this to be answered *now*? That's why we have historical locks.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I'm new here so I might not know all the history. If policy has changed, then why leave this question open if not to elicit further responses?

Comment: Don't underestimate the Meta effect, this question may well end up closed if yours get more visibility. I'm not voting to because it's old and it has good answers, but I'm not sure these answers warrant a historical lock either... time (and the community) will tell.

Comment: OK Frederic, seems we will just go around in circles on this. Seems to me that the 'policy' discourages anything but trivial answers to black & white questions. But I won't take up anymore of your time. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just to be clear, linking to an offsite resource - even your own - is fine provided 1) there is full disclosure (which you had), and 2) you excerpt the target back here on SO. We're not asking you to cut and paste, just summarise then link to the detailed resource. Answers that don't excerpt or summarise get deleted - as a link and no explanation they are not good answers.